# Vue js showing 2 table value

Tags: vue.js

My array like:

```
[
{
    "id": 01,
    "no": "ABC",
    "offer": [
        {
            "offer_no": "ABC_01",
        },
        {
            "offer_no": "ABC_02",
        },
        {
           "offer_no": "ABC_05",
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 02,
    "no": "EFG",
    "offer": [
        {
            "offer_no": "EFG_01",
        },
    ]
}
]
```

Here i want to show:

no--------------offer

ABC　　　　ABC_01

ABC_02

ABC_05

EFG　　　　EFG_01

how can i show that in vue js?

i try before:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <template v-for="item in array_list">
            <template v-for="offer in item.offer">
                <tr>
                    <th>{{item.no}}</th>
                    <th>{{offer.offer_no}}</th>
                </tr>
            </template>
        </template>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

no--------------offer

ABC　　　　ABC_01

ABC　　　　ABC_02

ABC　　　　ABC_05

EFG　　　　EFG_01

but the result not my preferred

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <template v-for="item in array_list">
            <template v-for="(offer,index) in item.offer">
                <tr>
                    <td><div v-show = "index ==0">{{item.no}}</div></td>
                    <td>{{offer.offer_no}}</td>
                </tr>
            </template>
        </template>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use the index and only show the ABC/EFG-item when the index equals 0.